# How to give runtime name to Dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#

I am making application in c#. In that application i want to create the dictionary run time.Here i am getting data from different ports like 1000,2000,3000 etc. Here i want to create the dictionary run time with name as Dictionary1000, Dictionary2000, Dictionary3000 etc. But i am not able to do it. Please help me.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: What dictionary are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry Dany, It's difficult to understand your question. Maybe giving us some code would help explain?

Comment: Here my dictionary is like  Dictionary<int, string> in which i am storing the received data from that particular port. To differentiate easily i want to add port number into name of dictionary name.

Comment: Really you want Dictionary<IPEndPoint,Dictionary<int,string>> because ports are only unique to a given IP address binding.

Comment: What you mean is a runtime dictionary, not a dictionary runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never variable name for indexing. Use a dictionary of dictionary.

Comment: Can you tell me easiest way to differentiate dictionary for every port as i am getting data  from many ports

Comment: It's given to you already :) Dictionary.TryGetValue :) port numer should be the key of the outer dictionary

Answer (score 3):

This kind of approach would not be very practical. Why not use a dictionary of dictionaries? Something like:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<SomeType,SomeOtherType>>
```

so you can store a dictionary against each port in question

Answer (score 2):

```
public class NamedDictionary<TKey,TValue> : Dictionary<TKey,TValue> {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

...?

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve the problem by creating a new type, that holds a composite key.

```
public class PortDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<CompositeKey, MyValueType> _store = new Dictionary<CompositeKey, MyValueType>();

    public void Add(int port, MyKeyType key, MyValueType value)
    {
        _store.Add(new CompositeKey(port, key), value);
    }

    public void Remove(int port, MyKeyType key)
    {
        _store.Remove(new CompositeKey(port, key));
    }

    public bool TryGet(int port, MyKeyType key, out MyValueType value)
    {
        return _store.TryGetValue(new CompositeKey(port, key), out value);
    }

    private class CompositeKey : IEquatable<CompositeKey>
    {
        private int _port;
        private MyKeyType _key;

        public CompositeKey(int port, MyKeyType key)
        {
            _port = port;
            _key = key;
        }

        #region IEquatable<IdentityKey> Members

        public bool Equals(CompositeKey other)
        {
            if (_port != other._port) {
                return false;
            }
            return _key == other._key;
        }

        #endregion

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _port.GetHashCode() ^ _key.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

In this implementation the composite key is a local class that is hidden inside the port dictionary. The composite key must implement IEquatable<> and must override GetHashCode() in order to be able to use it as key in a dictionary.

Here is an example of how you can use this port dictionary:

```
var dict = new PortDictionary();
dict.Add(3000, myKey, myValue);

//Retrieve
if (dict.TryGet(3000, myKey, out myValue)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Value = {0}", myValue);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("No value found for port {0} and key {1}", 3000, myKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick to make things simple, is to overwrite this[]:

```
public class InnerDictionary : Dictionary<int, string>
{
}

public class OuterDictionary : Dictionary<int, InnerDictionary>
{
    public new InnerDictionary this[int key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!base.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                base.Add(key, new InnerDictionary());
            }

            return base[key];
        }

        set { throw new NotSupportedException("Message"); }
    }
}
```